# Jquery getJSON cach issue?

Tags: jquery, caching, getjson

I'm using getJSON to get data from a WCF. The app works for a few times and after that it seems to get data from cache. The problem occures ion Firefox, Chrome. In internet explorer 9 i can't get any of the data.

```
function get_WCF() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $.getJSON('http://192.168.1.8:9100/PraticaService.svc/GetAllQueries', {
                idPratica : $("#txtIdPratica").val() + "M"
            }, function(json) {
                json = jQuery.parseJSON(json.d.GetAllQueries);
                if(json.$values[0].$values[0]) {
                    $('#txtCognomeRagioneSociale').val(json.$values[3].$values[0].DENOMINAZIONE);}
            })
        };
```

Comment: "The app works for a few times and after that it seems to get data from cache" If its caching issue it should work only once and then get cached data.

Comment: Are you returning JSON as a string inside a JSON result? Isn't that a bit redundant?

Comment: Monitor you ajax requests using the developer tools of your browsers. You will see whether the response are fetched from the cache rather than from the server. You also see the response data which may help to pin down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();

$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.8:9100/PraticaService.svc/GetAllQueries?' + time, {..
```

for prevent caching, adding a random string at end.